# No image with correct dimenstions found warning in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've used the http://appicontemplate.com/ template for Photoshop to create my app icon, but I noticed that most of these templates only export the following, but what do I do about the remaining resolutions with a warning?

Icon-72.png

Icon-72@2x.png

Icon-Small-50.png

Icon-Small-50@2x.png

Icon-Small.png

Icon-Small@2x.png

Icon.png

Icon@2x.png

iTunesArtwork.png

iTunesArtwork@2x.png

[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating them and adding them to your project?

Comment: I find it very odd that every template I tried outputs the same resolutions and doesn't give you the ones I'm missing. You are correct I could go create them in those resolutions, but are these required? Will it default to another resolution if I don't add them?

Comment: The missing images are new as of iOS 7, that is why few, if any, templates don't include them. I believe that since Apple is now requiring app submissions to work with iOS 7 that the icons are required now too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons on the iPhone home screen have received a slight increase in size up from 114px and 57px to 120 px and 60px respectively.

Try using the newest iOS 7 template:
http://appicontemplate.com/ios7

Alternatively you can try the following: http://ios.robs.im/